# Calculate inverse log-norm in Go

Tags: excel, go, math, statistics

I'm attempting to convert an Excel formula to Go and need to calculate the inverse log-norm i.e. LOGNORM.INV in Excel.

In Python this would be:

```
def lognorminv(x, mu, sigma):
    return sp.lognorm(s=sigma, scale=np.exp(mu)).ppf(x)
```

But I can't seem to find an equivalent in Go.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gonum` package, It has various methods for `lognormal`.

- https://github.com/gonum/gonum/
- https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/master/stat/distuv/lognormal.go
- https://godoc.org/gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat/distuv#LogNormal